# why is the mod Rewrite Rule not working?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have tried using this code:

```
Rewrite Rule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    add-category/?cid=$1    [NC,L]
```

But it is not working.

My url is `http://webmicrodemo.com/haraz/ad-category/index.php?cid=9`

and I want to change it to `http://webmicrodemo.com/haraz/cat/9`

Comment: This can have like 1 million causes, one of which is that mod_rewrite is not installed at all, so .htaccess files are ignored. Please improve your question by 1) checking if everything is installed correctly, and 2) what you have tried and what the results where (server errors? Which ones? redirect loops?)

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772/476

Answer (score 0):

**You must have to write it in proper format.The correct way is given below**

```
#This is for listing active product page
RewriteRule ^(add-category)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/$ index.php?cid=$3
RewriteRule ^(add-category)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?cid=$3
```

Comment: I use above rule but not resolved. ihave checked mode_rewrite is installed.